# Confusing .net memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, memory, clr

A process memory usage include (can be called as VirtualMemory):

- PrivateMemmory: dedicated to a process and cannot be shared by other processes.
- SharedMemory: runtime or 3rd linked library.
- CommitedMemory [or PagedMemory]: mapped out to the hard disk. (ready for use)
- ReservedMemory: only declared(not exist and no address).

Here is my understanding:

```
Virtual Memory = PrivateMemmory + SharedMemory + CommitedMemory + ReservedMemory;
WorkSet Memory = PrivateMemmory + SharedMemory + CommitedMemory;
Free Memory = 'Virtual Memory' - 'WorkSet Memory';
```

I calculate total usage memory of a process (not include the reserved) written with c#. the left is VMMap and the right is VS Monitor.

The process total memory size is about 5GB, and the reserved memory is about 4GB in VMMap, and VS Monitor show VirtualMemorySize64 is about 5GB, i am confused how can i get the total usage memory. there is 4GB of the reserved memory in  VMMap, how can i get the reserved memory with .net Process class.

I set TotalUsageMemory value with below code, is it correct?

```
Int64 TotalUsageMemory = proc.WorkingSet64 + proc.PagedMemorySize64;
```

[image: .net process report with VMMap]

Comment: What is your question ? 
"I set CurrentMemory value with below code, is it corrected?"
Or why you have so much memoryusage ?

Comment: No, that is nonsensical, you'll count the same kind of memory twice.  The word "memory" is far too vague on a demand-page virtual memory operating system like Windows.  Pursuing the VMMap number is not very useful, there is a bunch of it that is shared by all processes so not exactly representative of the "load" you put on the machine.  Process.PrivateMemorySize64 is a decent measure.

Comment: @podosta I update the question. I want to get the total usage memory of a process (have memory addresses, the reserved memory only declared with no address), there is 4GB of the reserved memory from VMMap, but .net Process class only tell me the virtual memory, workset memory, private memory, paged memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers don't add up like that. Whether a page is in the working set or not is independent of whether it is shared or not. This again is (I believe) independent of whether it is committed or not.

The right counter to look at depends on the question you want to answer. Unfortunately, there is no counter that fully matches the intuitive notion of memory usage. Private bytes normally is what's used for that. Working set does not mean much in practice. This counter can change at any time due to OS actions. Virtual memory also is quite irrelevant from a performance standpoint.

Normally, memory usage is the memory that was incrementally consumed by starting that process. That's private bytes.

There exists no counter or computation to give you a `TotalUsageMemory` value.